# Query for datas pe hour & count total carton

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, select

I'm a newbie, and I have a table like the one below. I need to retrieve data like below's result. Could you advise how to get this result?

I want a result like this:

```
date count(ref_no) count(ctn_no) sum(quantity)

00:00am to 08:00 4 5 10000

08:01am to 12:00pm

12:01pm to 18:00pm
18:01 to 23:59pm 00 00 000


tbl_pack
insert_date ref_no ctn_no serial_no quantity

03/09/2012 13:12:53:837 I2280097 34 1 T3BSB 500
03/09/2012 13:12:53:867 I2280097 34 2 T3BSA 500
03/09/2012 13:12:53:893 I2280097 34 3 T3BS9 500
03/09/2012 13:12:53:923 I2280097 34 4 T1NJR 500
03/09/2012 13:13:37:453 I2280097 35 1 T29KU 2000
03/09/2012 13:13:37:483 I2280097 35 2 T29KT 2000
03/09/2012 13:13:37:51 I2280097 35 3 T29KS 2000
03/09/2012 13:25:11:907 I2280102 1 1 T491Q 400
03/09/2012 13:25:11:953 I2280102 1 2 T491S 400
03/09/2012 13:25:11:983 I2280102 1 3 T491U 400
```

Comment: Aren't there five fields after the data (example:  I2280097 34 1 T3BSB 500)?.

Answer (score 0):

I've renamed the table fields slightly differently, because I didn't fully know how to interpret the fields in the provided data, so my example query solution may not be exactly as you intended, but it should be close.  I suspect that you also want to show the actual RefNumber and maybe the CartonNumber, but that's just guessing.

tbl_pack:
`CalendarDateTime       RefNumber   CartonNumber    SequenceNumber  SerialNumber    Quantity

3/9/2012 13:12:53:837   I2280097    34  1   T3BSB   500

3/9/2012 13:12:53:867   I2280097    34  2   T3BSA   500

3/9/2012 13:12:53:893   I2280097    34  3   T3BS9   500

3/9/2012 13:12:53:923   I2280097    34  4   T1NJR   500

3/9/2012 13:13:37:453   I2280097    35  1   T29KU   2000

3/9/2012 13:13:37:483   I2280097    35  2   T29KT   2000

3/9/2012 13:13:37:510   I2280097    35  3   T29KS   2000

3/9/2012 13:25:11:907   I2280102    1   1   T491Q   400

3/9/2012 13:25:11:953   I2280102    1   2   T491S   400

3/9/2012 13:25:11:983   I2280102    1   3   T491U   400`

Then this query will do what you were asking for:

```
SELECT  
    CONVERT(varchar(10), CalendarDateTime, 111),  
    (  
        CASE   
            WHEN datepart(hh,CalendarDateTime) * 60 + datepart(mi,CalendarDateTime) <= 8*60 THEN '0:00am To 8:00am'  
            WHEN datepart(hh,CalendarDateTime) * 60 + datepart(mi,CalendarDateTime) between 8*60 + 1 and 12*60 THEN '8:00am To 12:00pm'  
            WHEN datepart(hh,CalendarDateTime) * 60 + datepart(mi,CalendarDateTime) between 12*60 + 1 and 18*60 THEN '12:00pm To 18:00pm'  
            WHEN datepart(hh,CalendarDateTime) * 60 + datepart(mi,CalendarDateTime) between 18*60 + 1 and 24 * 60 - 1 THEN '6:00pm To 23:59pm'  
        END  
    ) as TimePeriod,  
    COUNT(RefNumber) as CountRefNumber,  
    COUNT(CartonNumber) as CountCartonNumber,  
    SUM(Quantity) as SumQuantity 
FROM tbl_pack  
GROUP BY  
    CONVERT(varchar(10), CalendarDateTime, 111),   
    (  
        CASE   
            WHEN datepart(hh,CalendarDateTime) * 60 + datepart(mi,CalendarDateTime) <= 8*60 THEN '0:00am To 8:00am'  
            WHEN datepart(hh,CalendarDateTime) * 60 + datepart(mi,CalendarDateTime) between 8*60 + 1 and 12*60 THEN '8:00am To 12:00pm'  
            WHEN datepart(hh,CalendarDateTime) * 60 + datepart(mi,CalendarDateTime) between 12*60 + 1 and 18*60 THEN '12:00pm To 18:00pm'  
            WHEN datepart(hh,CalendarDateTime) * 60 + datepart(mi,CalendarDateTime) between 18*60 + 1 and 24 * 60 - 1 THEN '6:00pm To 23:59pm'  
        END  
    )
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, is good query but total RefNumber CartonNumber is not total row. I need total as I given . I count manually sample given total RefNumber is 2 and  CartonNumber is 3 .

Comment: Ah. Then you need to add the keyword distinct: `Count(Distinct RefNumber)`. Same for CartonNumber